# Ways to remember and reuse previous query result in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neography

I am coding in Ruby using Neo4j with the gem Neography. When doing query, I use the method execute_neo4j_query provided by Neography. I am not sure about the best practice.

Suppose I use following code to fetch a user:

```
user1 = @neo.execute_neo4j_query("
      MATCH (user:User {user_id: '#{params[:user_id_1]}'})
      RETURN id(user)
      LIMIT 1
      ")
```

and to fetch another user similarly

```
user2 = @neo.execute_neo4j_query("
      MATCH (user:User {user_id: '#{params[:user_id_2]}'})
      RETURN id(user)
      LIMIT 1
      ")
```

Then I did some stuff with this two users.

Now I need to create an edge between this two users, so I did this

```
@neo.execute_neo4j_query("
      MATCH (user1:User {user_id: '#{params[:user_id_2]}'})
      MATCH (user2:User {user_id: '#{params[:user_id_2]}'})
      CREATE UNIQUE (user1)-[:FOLLOW]->(user2)
      ")
```

However, I believe such approach is not optimal, since I queried for the same two users twice.

My question is:

1) Is there a way to reuse previously queried results using Neography?

2) Is it recommended to use methods provided by Neography such as @neo.create_node other than using execute_neo4j_query directly? I choose the latter because I am not sure if the encapsulated methods can satisfy my task. So, if you can rewrite my above codes in native Neography code, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use start anymore if you don't know why you would use it
2. use the transactional [cypher support in neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/wiki/Transactions)
3. Use Parameters in your cypher queries, like `MATCH (u:User {name:{name}}) RETURN u`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Neography, but I can take a shot at answering question #1, since that appears to be answerable by changing your third Cypher query.

Since your 2 initial queries seem to be getting the node IDs for user 1 and user 2, you should be able to avoid searching again for those nodes by using the `START` clause. You will need to specify a parameter map with the 2 node IDs returned by the first 2 queries.

```
  START user1=node(#{params[:node_id_1]}), user2=node(#{params[:node_id_2]})
  CREATE UNIQUE (user1)-[:FOLLOW]->(user2)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think even querying using ids will take some time to search along the index tree. I am thinking that, given I have done the query once, if it is possible to store the exact object for reuse, such as creating a pointer pointing to the fetched users, or a variable storing the object. Put aside Neography, if it is possible using Cypher?

Comment: I think specifying a node by node ID is as close as you can get to a node "pointer"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Neography either, but you can simplify the query slightly, with this one liner:

```
   MATCH (a:User),(b:User) WHERE a.userId ={id1} AND b.userId = {id2} CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(b) RETURN r
```